# Using dplyr group_by to find the fraction of each group with score >= 2?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe called `splicing` in R that looks like the following (simplified):

```
Site    PhyloP_n
50      -1.546
50      -1.546
50      -1.546
49      2.125
49      2.125
48      -0.282
48      -0.282
47      0.596
47      0.596
46      3.561
46      3.561
```

Each `Site` has multiple `PhyloP_n` scores in the full dataframe. What I'm trying to do is get the fraction with a PhyloP_n score >= 2 at each Site. Currently, this is how I've set it up, but it's not working:

```
splicing_high_phylop <- splicing %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  filter(PhyloP_n >= 2 )
  dplyr::summarize(Fraction = (sum(PhyloP_n >= 2, na.rm = TRUE) / tally()))
```

**Expected output:**

```
Site      Fraction with PhyloP_n >= 2
50        0.3
49        0.1
48        0.04
47        0.21
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  summarise(Frac = sum(PhyloP_n >= 2, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(Frac = Frac/sum(Frac))
```

Here, we first count number of `PhyloP_n >= 2` in each `Site` and then calculate the overall ratio.

---

We can also do this in base R using  `aggregate`

```
df1 <- aggregate(PhyloP_n~Site, df, function(x) sum(x >= 2, na.rm = TRUE))
df1$Frac <- df1$PhyloP_n/sum(df1$PhyloP_n)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` methods.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Site', get the `sum` of logical vector (`PhyloP_n >=2`), and then update the 'Frac' by dividing with the `sum` of 'Frac'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Frac = sum(PhyloP_n >=2, na.rm = TRUE)),
     by = Site][, Frac := Frac/sum(Frac)][]
```